# Fail to expose my pod to the internet

Tags: nginx, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have tried some example to run a specific image on my kubernetes cluster, I did this command:

```
kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80
```

then:

```
kubectl expose rc my-nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
```

and when I go:

```
kubectl get service
```

I get:

```
NAME         LABELS                                    SELECTOR       IP(S)         PORT(S)
kubernetes   component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes   <none>         10.0.0.1      443/TCP
my-nginx     run=my-nginx                              run=my-nginx   10.0.100.19   80/TCP
```

now, I have a cluster that I created with my kubernetes, and onw I want to put something in my browser and see the landing page of nginx...

I tried to put my master machine ip with port 80 in the end and it didnt work, what should I do?
thanks!!

describe svc:

```
Name:           my-nginx
Namespace:      default
Labels:         run=my-nginx
Selector:       run=my-nginx
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         x.x.xxx.xx
LoadBalancer Ingress:   dasfasdgfgaasok23o4j34ij4ofa69da-1772099277.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   31331/TCP
Endpoints:      x.x.xxx.x:80,xx.xxx.x.x:80
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

Comment: Are you running a kubernetes cluster locally or on GKE or somewhere else?

Comment: @VishnuKannan im running the cluster in aws

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl describe svc my-nginx`?

Comment: @VishnuKannan added to the question bro

Comment: Great! Did you try accessing dasfasdgfgaasok23o4j34ij4ofa69da-1772099277.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com? You are supposed to be able to access the LoadBalancer IP. `kubectl get svc my-nginx -o wide` should show you the external IP.

Comment: what do you mean by `accessing dasfasdgfgaasok23o4j34ij4ofa69da-1772099277.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`? accessing how? I can see the ip when I do `kubectl get svc my-nginx -o wide`, but how do I put it in the browser?

Comment: The external IP you get as part of `kubectl get svc` is what you'd put in the browser. That IP will be redirected to one of the containers backing the service.